# Only one message passes through pipe

Tags: c, pipe

I've been doing this assignment over and over again, this is about the 10th version. The problem is that only one message passes through the pipe, and the correct result is computed. The following strings don't pass at all, or after fiddling with the buffers only some characters. Please help, I've really lost a lot of time on this one and I need to learn this stuff for a test coming soon.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio_ext.h>

/* Prototypes */

void usage(void);
void calchild(void);

char command[] = "<not yet set>";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char input1[512];
  char input2[512];
  char tmp[512];
  char *endptr;
  char c = 0;
  int a, b, result;
  pid_t cpid;
  int status = 0;
  int stocpipe[2]; /* Server to client pipe. [0] -read; [1]- write*/
  int ctospipe[2]; /* Client to server pipe.       - || -         */
  int i = 0;
  FILE *send, *receive;

  if(argc > 1)
    {
      usage();
    }

  /* Pipe Setup */
  if(pipe(stocpipe) != 0 || pipe(ctospipe) != 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Can't create unnamed pipe! \n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  switch(cpid = fork())
    {
    case -1:
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Can't fork! \n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      break;
    case 0:
      /* calchild */
      close(stocpipe[1]);
      close(ctospipe[0]);

      receive = fdopen(stocpipe[0], "r");
      send = fdopen(ctospipe[1], "w");

/*Gets the string from the parent process and does the computation.*/
      while(fgets(input2, 17, receive) != NULL)
        {
      strcpy(tmp, input2);
      fprintf(stdout, "After receive: %s", tmp);
      a = strtol(tmp, &endptr, 10);
      fprintf(stdout, "a = %d\n", a);
      b = strtol(endptr, &endptr, 10); 
      fprintf(stdout, "b = %d\n", b);
      c = endptr[0];

/*Loops until it finds a non-space char*/
      for(i = 0; isspace(c = endptr[i]); i++);

      switch(c)
    {
    case '+':
      /*add*/
      result = a + b;
      break;
    case '-':
      /*subtract*/
      result = a - b;
      break;
    case '*':
      /*multiply*/
      result = a * b;
      break;
    case '/':
      /*divide*/
      result = a / b;
      break;
    default:
      fprintf(stderr, "the funk!? %c\n", c);
      break;
    }

      fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", result);
      fprintf(send, "%d", result);

    }
      break;
    default:

  close(stocpipe[0]);
  close(ctospipe[1]);

  send = fdopen(stocpipe[1], "w");
  receive = fdopen(ctospipe[0], "r");

/*Reads string from stdin and sends it to the child process through a pipe. */
  while(fgets(input1, 17, stdin) != NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stdout, "Before send: %s", input1);
      fwrite(input1, 17, 1, send);

if(fflush(send) == EOF)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Flush error!");
  }
}

  (void) waitpid(cpid, &status, 0);
  if(status != 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Child calculator exited with %d \n", status);
    }
      break;
   }


  return 0;
}

void usage(void)
{
  fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s", command);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The program is a calculator. The aim of it is learning IPC. The parent process accepts strings from stdin(e.g. 3 5 +) and sends it to the child. The child parses the string and computes the result. Then it sends the result back to the parent process which then prints it to stdout.

I got stuck on the part of sending the string to the child. The first string accepted gets sent to the child. And it computes the result fine. The second string and every after that is empty or at least it seems like empty.

Comment: Nested `switch/while/swicth` and a bodyless `for`? Neat. Really, really hard to read though. Make functions for the parent and child processing, and try to un-nest your code a bit. (And indent it correctly.)

Comment: I think you need make the program easier to understand.  First try to  give use a cut-down minimal program the shows the same bad behaviour; also explain what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: I've added a comment for the bodyless for. :D I've already done it with separate functions, even separate executables, now they're separated in the switch. Also, I've written what it does, and comments where the sending and receiving is done(the part where the problem occurs). The problem could even be that I've chosen the wrong buffer sizes or sth. I couldn't find the problem in 2 days... :-/

Comment: Go back to separate functions. This code is an unreadable mess.

Comment: And yes, at least please adjust the indending!

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the line `fwrite(input1, 17, 1, send);`. The **parent** process may have sent random stuff after '\n' character to **child** process. In **child** `while(fgets(input2, 17, receive) != NULL)`, `fgets` stops while getting '\n' and may get less than 17-1 characters. Its next reading pipe  will get random stuff.

One immediate fix is `fwrite(input1, strlen(input1), 1, send);`. Referring to 'man fwrite', it's better to use `fwrite(input1, sizeof (input1[0]), strlen(input1), send);`.

Anyway using magic number 17 is dangerous. Keep in mind PIPE is a continuous character stream.